# Git pull creates merge by the 'recursive' strategy

Tags: git, gitlab

*Foreword after finding solution: "side-effect" of default `git pull` behavior have been observed, because I have a two sources of changes on master branch - me and GitLab. Similar situation could arise if two persons would work on the same branch.*

I have an issue with git and GitLab. My workflow is:

1. *GitLab:* Create Merge Request with branch `issue-branch` to the issue.
2. `git pull` on local repository.
3. `git checkout issue-branch`
4. Changes on the branch.
5. `git push` after all.
6. *GitLab:* accept MR with delete branch.
7. `git status` - no changes.
8. `git checkout master` then `git pull`.

**Expected result:** source code pulled and ready to next work.

**Actual result:** `git` creates new, local merge. I see output like this:

```
 $ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From gitlab.com:username/project
   dfb8bca..04998ee  master     -> origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 somefile.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 somefile.txt

$ git shortlog
      Merge branch 'issue-branch' into 'master' // made by GitLab
      Merge branch 'master' of gitlab.com:username/project // made by git pull

$ git config --list
credential.helper=manager
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
user.name=XYZ
user.email=xyz@gmail.com
merge.tool=meld
merge.ff=false
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
mergetool.kdiff3.keepbackup=false
mergetool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
mergetool.meld.cmd=meld $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE --output $MERGED
diff.tool=meld
difftool.prompt=false
difftool.meld.cmd=meld $LOCAL $REMOTE
credential.helper=manager
alias.df=difftool
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=abcdefg
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.1-is-working-or-not.remote=origin
branch.1-is-working-or-not.merge=refs/heads/1-is-working-or-not
branch.2-abc.remote=origin
branch.2-abc.merge=refs/heads/2-abc
```

Why git creates one more merge? It shouldn't work in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given enough information. Any number of things could cause `git pull` to make a merge commit. It is possible that your `pull.ff` was set to `false`. It is possible that your `merge.ff` was set to `false`.

(**EDIT:** In a subsequent edit, you revealed that, sure enough, your `merge.ff` *is* set to `false`. That explains what happened, since `git pull`, by default, *is* a merge.)

The broader lesson here, however, is that who lives by the `git pull` dies by the `git pull`. You should basically *never* say `git pull`. There is no need for it, and (as you've seen) it rips the control from your hands. Instead, say `git fetch` and now do a merge or a rebase of the remote tracking branch into the local branch, giving any specific options you care to *on this occasion*. (As you rightly point out, `git pull` also lets you set some specific options, which would have solved the problem on this one occasion.)

Comment: OK, I updated question by `git config --list`. Yes, I have a `merge.ff=false`. So I don't want fast forward for merge, due to history (git flow etc.), but pull I would like to be fast forward (to not create unnecessary node). Does it makes sense or I have a wrong approach?

Comment: Good update! What you have is fine, but what you didn't take account of is that `git pull`, by default, _is_ a merge. Therefore it is affected by your `merge.ff=false`. Now you have overridden that with your `pull.ff` setting. So the phenomenon that you experienced is completely explained by my answer, and the settings that you now have will fix the problem exactly.

Comment: By the way, just for clarity (and in case this comment lives on — sometimes they don't, which is fine), your question has nothing to do with GitLab or the merge strategy. So the title and the tags are misleading. What you're describing is all git all the time. :)

Comment: You are right, but I experienced it due to using GitLab. In the past I was the only source of changes, so I didn't in reality use `git pull`, now when I use MR on GitLab I have changes from outside/second user, but yes... title and/or content should point relation between not GitLab but in general when two users puts changes on branches and `git pull` is used.

Comment: Agreed, I think for someone who has never cooperated with another user you're doing very well actually. My first PR was a harrowing experience.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull --ff` solves issue, but I don't know why git doesn't detect that ff should be used.

For now I will end with configuration `git config --global pull.ff only` to avoid such issue.

Answer (score 0):

as above comment, in my case, this is

> why git doesn't detect that ff should be used

, as below

I was in `335d100` and `verify_audio_and_read_about_related_params_of_ffmpeg` (not `params_of_ffmpeg_`) branch, after `git pull --ff`, it became

[image]

`git diff 0f1ec96 0e89e68` and it is nothing, I need to rebase all 5 commits `git rebase -i HEAD~5` and everything is as expected

[image]